# Property 'index' does not exist on type 'Ingredient', angular8

Tags: angular, typescript

I am try to learn Angular(ngrx) from tutorial.

my action file is like this:

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Ingredient } from 'src/app/shared/ingredient.model';

export const ADD_INGREDIENT = 'ADD_INGREDIENT';
export const ADD_INGREDIENTS = 'ADD_INGREDIENTS';
export const UPDATE_INGREDIENT = 'UPDATE_INGREDIENT';
export const DELETE_INGREDIENT = 'DELETE_INGREDIENT';

interface IUpdatePayload {
    index: number;
    ingredient: Ingredient
}



export class AddIngredient implements Action {
    readonly type: string = ADD_INGREDIENT;
    constructor(public payload: Ingredient) {}
}

export class AddIngredients implements Action {
    readonly type = ADD_INGREDIENTS;

    constructor(public payload: Ingredient[]) {}
}

export class UpdateIngredient implements Action {
    readonly type = UPDATE_INGREDIENT;
    constructor(public payload: {index: number, ingredient: Ingredient}) {}
}

export class DeleteIngredient implements Action {
    readonly type = DELETE_INGREDIENT;
    constructor(public payload: number) {}
}



export type ShoppingListActions = 
AddIngredient | 
AddIngredients | 
UpdateIngredient | 
DeleteIngredient;
```

Reducer file is like this

```
import { Ingredient } from '../../shared/ingredient.model';
import * as ShoppingListActions from './shopping-list.actions';

const initialState = {
    ingredients: [
        new Ingredient('Apples', 5),
        new Ingredient('Tomatoes', 10),
    ]
};

export function shoppingListReducer(
    state = initialState, 
    action: ShoppingListActions.ShoppingListActions
) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ShoppingListActions.ADD_INGREDIENT:
            return { 
                ...state, 
                ingredients: [...state.ingredients, action.payload] 
            };
        case ShoppingListActions.ADD_INGREDIENTS:
            return {
                ...state,
                ingredients: [...state.ingredients, ...action.payload]
            }
        case ShoppingListActions.UPDATE_INGREDIENT:
            const ingredient = state.ingredients[action.payload.index];
            const updatedIngredient = {
                ...ingredient,
                ...action.payload.ingredient
            }
            return {
                ...state,
                ingredients: [...state.ingredients]
            };
        case ShoppingListActions.DELETE_INGREDIENT:
            return {};
        default: return state
    }
}
```

i am getting error in `case ShoppingListActions.UPDATE_INGREDIENT:` at **action.payload.index** that `Property 'index' does not exist on type 'Ingredient | { index: number; ingredient: Ingredient; }'.
  Property 'index' does not exist on type 'Ingredient'.`

Not sure what i am doing wrong. Need some help.
thanks

Comment: The error seems to come from `state.ingredients[action.payload.index]` This is sometimes of type Ingredient and sometimes of type IUpdatePayload. Only the latter has an index.The type UpdateIngredient  also has no property index.

Comment: @CarloBos, i cant see any problem in code, i just followed the tutorial line by line. any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you provide the link to the tutorial you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

In your action file, in the first export class, you need to change

```
readonly type: string = ADD_INGREDIENT;
```

to

```
readonly type = ADD_INGREDIENT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
readonly type: string = ADD_INGREDIENT;
```

to

```
readonly type = ADD_INGREDIENT;
```

but the problem is not solved until I removed the string type for all the classes in the action file.

[image: inessential obnoxious picture of code]

[image: even more inessential obnoxious picture of code]